# how to extract text from a html website in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to develop an android application which takes a particular input from the app and gives it to a website, then the website fetches the result. I want to display this result from the website and display it in the android app. I tried using xml parsing but the website is not a xml based website. The website is **http://www.fastvturesults.com/** and the input is a roll number(usn number). Can anyone guide me on how to fecth the result from this site and parse it to the app.

Comment: use `webservice` like `ksoap`

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSOUP](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/) which extracts datas from website and display the result.

```
   Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Get the html document title
            String title = document.title(); //get title
    Elements description = document
                    .select("meta[name=description]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            String desc = description.attr("content");
```

and so on.

Comment: i tried jsoup but it is not able to extract the whole text from the site